# Azure blob storage upload gets killed

Tags: node.js, azure

I am using the NPM package to upload a blob file to my azure storage account. Im doing this with the following code:

```
root@server:/backup# azure storage blob upload -a "accoutname" -k "mykey" "filename.tar.gz" "backup" "filename.tar.gz" -q
```

The response i am receiving from the package is the following:

> info:    Executing command storage blob upload
>   + Uploading file.tar.gz to blob filename.tar.gz in container backup
>   Percentage: 0.0% (0B/423.34MB) Average Speed: 0B/S Elapsed Time: 00:00:04 Killed

As you can see the upload is not really doing much where it worked perfectly in the past. It also seems that all credentials and everything is entered correctly else the upload would not even get started.

I already started the "npm update" and there was not a package update.

Anyone with a solution would be very helpfull.

*UPDATE*
I just did a test using the Azure Storage Explorer and uploading using that tool is working like a charm. Seems like a NPM bug or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems a bug in the SDK. For more details about this:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-tools-xplat/issues/1063